# Changing Python funtion call font color

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How can I change the font color of the function that I call in Python 3.6.8 in terminal?
I need to differentiate between the function called and its arguments as it becomes difficult to read when a lot of code is written. I am new to Python so apologies for asking a weird question in the first place. Thanks in advance. [Click to check how I need it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKFdO.png)

Comment: Could you please add text instead of the image.

Comment: In what?  There are many different things that could be called "terminal".  Editors have various colorizing schemes.  Using an IDE to work on your Python code will probably give you the colorization you want.

Comment: using IDLE helped. Thanks again.